# iOS Set shadow radius is not working

Tags: ios, uilabel, shadow

UILabel set shadow radius is not working.

```
[self.testLabel.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor purpleColor] CGColor]];
[self.testLabel.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(3, 3)];
[self.testLabel.layer setShadowRadius:5.0f];
[self.testLabel.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

My code (Google Drive)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5UPvOBH3cqvOFlvZHhKdlNhb0E/view?usp=sharing

I'm sorry if this's a repeat question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dear AdrianHor, I've tried but still not work X( https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5UPvOBH3cqvV2dKemVxaWxPeTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Dear AdrianHor, thank you very much. 
I can see the shadow effects if added this line....self.testLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

because of the [self.testLabel.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

this method will make the shadow invisible,  you can make a shadow image with a png/jpg formate, and put a imageview that had set the image below your textLabel to make it work..

and also you should set the opacity to 1..

```
//    self.testLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.testLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    [self.testLabel.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]];
    [self.testLabel.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(3, 3)];
    [self.testLabel.layer setShadowRadius:5.0f];
//    [self.testLabel.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

try this ..

Comment: Setting the opacity did it for me. Thx!